# No pilot light on gas oven?

Tags: oven, pilot-light

I have a Magic Chef in-wall oven, stove is separate by the way. The oven is gas. I was told it has no pilot light by some "help" person on another site.  Is there a pilot light on all gas ovens?  If so, where is it? Afraid to turn on knob to light along with a match.  lol

Comment: What's the model number?  A long time ago all gas appliances had a pilot light, as technologies changed and energy conservation became more important self lighting pilots or pilotless burners (that use heat and/or spark to ignite) have become a thing.

Comment: For a "long" time , gas ovens have had spark igniters like the range burners. The spark typically lights a gas pilot that heats a safety that then permits the main burner to come on. I expect there are some variations to this system.

Comment: You should be able to look it up with the model number, but if not, why not try turning on the oven for a short time to see if it lights by itself?  If it doesn't within a minute or so - or if you smell gas - then look into it further.

Comment: a magic chef oven  model #9112XUB    I do not know how old it is.  :(

Answer (score 3):

According to online documentation, this model uses a glow bar.  For an oven (not a stove top) one should NOT have to press any button to get anything to ignite - the thermostat and circuitry will take care of that for you, provided everything is intact and working.

If it were my oven, I'd open the door, remove the lower metal cover from within the oven (removing the grates first if necessary) and watch what happens when you turn the oven on.  With glow bar designs, for safety reasons, the gas valve may not even open if the glow bar has failed (when it generally becomes an open circuit).

In my experience, glow bars are not very reliable and yours may have failed "open".

Comment: When I looked I did not see the glow bar if the bar looks black do not touch the new one 1 little fingerprint will destroy it in a very short time possibly the first time, get a couple as these come broken often they are brittle and like I said 1 fingerprint causes them to overheat and crack.+

Answer (score 0):

Modern ovens / gas ranges / water heaters don't need pilot light as they use piezo-electric ignitors. So you have to look for a button to press to ignite the oven.

So just turn and press the knob and, few seconds after the fire lit, release the knob and adjust the temperature.

Comment: its a gas oven. and does not have an ignite button.

Comment: Sometimes the 'ignite' button is the same a your makers 'temperature' knob, that just have to be turned and kept pushed for a while the knob to ignite.  Anyway, you can always read the manual if you havn't it at home, just email the manufacturer and ask them for it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking line I only saw models with a pilot , I tried looking for spark and hot surface ignitors but did not find any thing other than the standing pilot for your model. The instructions say remove the broiler carriage , turn the thermostat past 140 hold a match at the top forward section of the pilot after the pilot lights the burner will light in 30 to 60 seconds, replace broiler carriage.

Comment: thats right, no ignitor. and i knew there was to be a light, Im just afraid itll blow up in my face or arms with a match.  ( a female here lol)

Comment: The gas won't turn on to the burner until the pilot has been lit for 30 seconds. My grandmother had a gas stove that had to be lit for each use she used to have matches that were over a foot long you might be more comfortable using those long matches.

Answer (score 0):

Not all ovens use piezo-electric, the Kenmore gas range/oven that my wife put in her rental apartment some time ago had a high temperature "glow" element.   It was basically a heating element that turned on when you first started the oven, and was hot enough to light the gas.

We had Sears service replace the unit several times because it would burn out.  (an the installers would screw it up)